# Swift Open Api Thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, parsing, grand-central-dispatch

I parse open API from web to my app. and it takes 1 min 15 sec to phrase all. It is too long for my app.

My app's logic is 'Launching page' -> 'Searching Page'. At the 'Searching Page', user can select six option(color, shape etc.) for filtering open Api. so My app should filtering the according to selected option, whether the parsing is not finished.

My question,
 1. Can I reduce the time for parsing, for example by using thread or any way?

2. If User select the option, before finishing phrasing open api,
   how can i provide some data located at the end of the row of open api?
3. Is there any best way to parsing and filtering by using multiple thread?

sorry my poor english  please suggest the best solution thanks.

```
//viewDidload()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            for i in 1..<207 {
            let url = "http://apis.data.go.kr/1470000/MdcinGrnIdntfcInfoService/getMdcinGrnIdntfcInfoList?serviceKey=VmiuEGJughm504SlGiaSfpQukd9mf27WJL2z2subLqfzG9DNUoYqKJ4KU6yHHdkrPuTo0CJwEZHGOhHqss9uFA%3D%3D&numOfRows=100&pageNo=\(i)"
            guard let xmlParser = XMLParser(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!) else { return }
            xmlParser.delegate = self;
            xmlParser.parse()
            }
        }
```

//parser delegate

```
public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
currentElement = elementName
if (elementName == "item") {
    pillItem = [String : String]()

    pillName = ""
    pillCompany = ""
    pillImage = ""
    pillFrontInprint = ""
    pillBackInprint = ""
    pillShape = ""
    pillFrontScore = ""
    pillBackScore = ""
    pillFrontColor = ""
    pillBackColor = ""
    pillLongSize = ""
    pillShortSize = ""
    pillThick = ""
    pillForm = ""
    pillChart = ""
    pillClassName = ""
    pillClassNum = ""
    pillEtcName = ""
}
```

}

```
public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

if (elementName == "item") {

    let pill = MFTemporaryPillModel(pillName: pillName, pillCompany: pillCompany, pillImage: pillImage, pillFrontInprint: pillFrontInprint,
    pillBackInprint: pillBackInprint, pillShape: pillShape, pillFrontScore: pillFrontScore, pillBackScore: pillBackScore,
    pillFrontColor: pillFrontColor, pillBackColor: pillBackColor, pillLongSize: pillLongSize, pillShortSize: pillShortSize,
    pillThick: pillThick, pillForm: pillForm, pillEfficacy: pillClassName, pillChart: pillChart, pillClassName: pillClassName,
    pillClassNum: pillClassNum, pillEtcName: pillEtcName)

    pillDataItems.append(pill)
}
```

}

```
public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
if (currentElement == "ITEM_NAME") { //이름
if pillName == "" {
  pillName = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "ENTP_NAME") { //회사이름
if pillCompany == "" {
pillCompany = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "CHART") { //성상
if pillChart == "" {
pillChart = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "ITEM_IMAGE") {//사진
if pillImage == "" {
pillImage = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "PRINT_FRONT") {
if pillFrontInprint == "" {
pillFrontInprint = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "PRINT_BACK") {
if pillBackInprint == "" {
pillBackInprint = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "DRUG_SHAPE") {
if pillShape == "" {
pillShape = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "COLOR_CLASS1") {
if pillFrontColor == "" {
pillFrontColor = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "COLOR_CLASS2") {
if pillBackColor == "" {
pillBackColor = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "LINE_FRONT") {
if pillFrontScore == "" {
pillFrontScore = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "LINE_BACK") {
if pillBackScore == "" {
pillBackScore = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "LENG_LONG") {
if pillLongSize == "" {
pillLongSize = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "LENG_SHORT") {
if pillShortSize == "" {
pillShortSize = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "THICK") {
if pillThick == "" {
pillThick = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "CLASS_NAME") { //분류번호에 있는거
if pillClassName == "" {
pillClassName = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "CLASS_NO") { //분류 번호
if pillClassNum == "" {
pillClassNum = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "FORM_CODE_NAME") {
if pillForm == "" {
pillForm = string
}
} else if (currentElement == "ETC_OTC_NAME") { //전문 기타 이런거
if pillEtcName == "" {
pillEtcName = string
}
}

}
```

}

//filtering func (when user select options)

```
func filteredPillData(filteredOption: [String : [String]]) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        self.filteredData.removeAll()
        for i in 0..<self.pillMap[1]!.count{
            let data: MFTemporaryPillModel = self.pillMap[1]![i]

            if (filteredOption["score"]?.contains(data.pillFrontScore))! && (filteredOption["color"]?.contains(data.pillFrontColor))! &&
                (filteredOption["form"]?.contains(data.pillForm))! && (filteredOption["shape"]?.contains(data.pillShape))! {
                self.filteredData.append(data)
                self.mMFSearchPillMainView.mMFSearchPillView.mMFDisplayPillDataCollection.pillDataArray = self.filteredData
            }
        }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.mMFSearchPillMainView.mMFSearchPillView.mMFDisplayPillDataCollection.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Comment: Sorry but this question is too vague and open ended. Focus on one specific issue and show relevant code about that one specific problem.

Comment: "Can I reduce the time for parsing" We don't know because you have not shown us _any_ code at all. If you want help with your code, show it.

Answer (score 1):

You're running this at the `.background` level. That is the level that means "I don't care if this completes today, or possibly ever." There is no promise that `.background` tasks will ever be scheduled, and they are given the least possible resources. If 1m15s is too slow, you didn't mean `.background`. Move this to `.utility` if the user is not waiting on it, and `.userInitiated` if the user is waiting on it. Then, if it's still too slow, run it through Instruments and see which piece is taking the longest time. Only then should you consider how to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, your server is supposed to be returning all the pages you need in a lump sum.

Change the way the server is responding with what you want otherwise you are going to be making the user wait for multiple little calls, instead of a bulk return.

Once you have a bulk return you should sort through it. Much faster...